# MARLIN training error: “You should override theLightningModule.lr_scheduler_step”

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-lightning

Hello I am trying to use MARLIN [enter link description here](https://github.com/ControlNet/MARLIN) and am getting stuck on the training step. After running the train.py with the appropriate locations for all of the files, this is what I get:

> C:\Users\AR\Desktop\marlin\MARLIN>python train.py --config config/pretrain/marlin_vit_base.yaml --data_dir C:\Users\AR\Desktop\marlin\MARLIN\trainingData\YouTubeFaces --n_gpus 1 --num_workers 8 --batch_size 16 --epochs 2000 --official_pretrained C:\Users\AR\Desktop\marlin\MARLIN\videomae\checkpoint_vitb.pth _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys=['encoder.pos_embedding.emb', 'decoder.pos_embedding.emb', 'discriminator.layers.0.linear.weight', 'discriminator.layers.0.linear.bias', 'discriminator.layers.1.linear.weight', 'discriminator.layers.1.linear.bias'], unexpected_keys=[]) GPU available: True (cuda), used: True TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs Missing logger folder: C:\Users\AR\Desktop\marlin\MARLIN\lightning_logs LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\AR\Desktop\marlin\MARLIN\train.py", line 141, in  trainer.fit(model, dm) File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 696, in fit self._call_and_handle_interrupt( File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 650, in _call_and_handle_interrupt return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 735, in _fit_impl results = self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path) File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1147, in _run self.strategy.setup(self) File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\strategies\single_device.py", line 74, in setup super().setup(trainer) File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\strategies\strategy.py", line 153, in setup self.setup_optimizers(trainer) File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\strategies\strategy.py", line 141, in setup_optimizers self.optimizers, self.lr_scheduler_configs, self.optimizer_frequencies = _init_optimizers_and_lr_schedulers( File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\optimizer.py", line 194, in _init_optimizers_and_lr_schedulers _validate_scheduler_api(lr_scheduler_configs, model) File "C:\Users\AR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\optimizer.py", line 351, in _validate_scheduler_api raise MisconfigurationException( pytorch_lightning.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: The provided lr scheduler LambdaLRdoesn't follow PyTorch's LRScheduler API. You should override theLightningModule.lr_scheduler_step hook with your own logic if you are using a custom LR scheduler.

What do I need to do to fix this error?

I am very new to all of this so forgive me for not knowing what extra information to provide about my environment. Feel free to tell me commands to run to give more info. Thank you!